# Manual Relationship query

Tags: ee2, relationships

I have a page that I want to list the entries in a channel, but I ONLY want the entry to be listed IF it has a relationship. So I am populating the filter with the following:

```
<h4>SHOW BY SERVICE</h4>
<ul>
    <li class="segment-1 selected-1 active"><a href="#" class="all">All</a></li>
    {exp:channel:entries 
        channel='service' 
        orderby='title' 
        sort='asc' 
        disable='categories|member_data|pagination'
    }
        <li class="segment-{count}">
            <a href="#" class="{url_title}" style="text-transform: capitalize;">{title}</a>
        </li>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```

I don't mind writing a custom query to do it, but I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(title) AS parent_title FROM exp_channel_titles WHERE entry_id IN ( SELECT DISTINCT(parent_id) AS parent FROM exp_relationships )
```

with no luck. Maybe I am over complicating things with this one. The rest of the page is under an entry loop in another channel:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel='success_story' 
    disable='categories|member_data' 
    orderby='date' 
    sort='desc'
}
    ...
```

The field is in the `Success Stories` channel as a relationship field named `{services_used}` which is pointing to the `Service` channel to relate it to the various services used.

I just need to be able to list the `Service` channel entries (distinctly) if they are referenced as used by a `Success Story` entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get what I needed using a query. I wasn't looking at the entries correctly in their relationships. I needed the children instead of the parents.

This is what I ended up with:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT title, url_title FROM exp_channel_titles WHERE entry_id IN ( SELECT DISTINCT(child_id) FROM exp_relationships ) ORDER BY title"}
    <li class="segment-{count}">
        <a href="#" class="{url_title}" style="text-transform: capitalize;">{title}</a>
    </li>
{/exp:query}
```